# Google BigQuery: diff single columns between different versions of the same row

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table which contains 2 columns, the previous status of a row and the current status of a row.
Every time a record changes, a new row is added to the table tracing the previous and current status of the fields.

For each couple (previous-current), I need to trace the actual fields that have changed, and the specific values.

Right now I achieved this using a UDF, which received the json representation the 2 status and check key by key what has changed.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION diffColumns(row_previous STRING, row_current STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<field_name STRING, value_previous STRING, value_current STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS r"""
    row_previous = row_previous ? JSON.parse(row_previous) : {};
    row_current = row_current ? JSON.parse(row_current) : {};
    
    var results = [];
    for(var key in row_previous) {
      if(row_previous[key] != row_current[key]) {
        results.push({
          field_name : key,
          value_previous : row_previous[key],
          value_current : row_current[key]
        });
      }
    }
    
    return results;

""";

WITH input_data AS (
  SELECT
    STRUCT("foo" AS field_1,1 AS field_2,CURRENT_DATE() AS field_3) AS row_previous,
    STRUCT("foo" AS field_1,2 AS field_2,CURRENT_DATE() AS field_3) AS row_current

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    STRUCT("foo" AS field_1,2 AS field_2,CURRENT_DATE() AS field_3) AS row_previous,
    STRUCT("bar" AS field_1,2 AS field_2,DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS field_3)AS row_current
)

SELECT
  TO_JSON_STRING(row_previous) AS row_previous,
  TO_JSON_STRING(row_current) AS row_current,
  diffColumns(TO_JSON_STRING(row_previous), TO_JSON_STRING(row_current)) AS diff

FROM input_data;
```

The achieved results is a table which contains an array which defines: the field that has changed, the previous value, the current value
[image]

For a pure better-performance improvement, I'm trying to understand if the same goal can be achieved with pure SQL approach. Is there a way to do this with a plain query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below:

```
select
  to_json_string(row_previous) as row_previous,
  to_json_string(row_current) as row_current,
  array(
    select as struct field_name, value_previous, value_current
    from (
      select * from unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(row_previous), '{}"', ''))) p,
      unnest([struct(split(p, ':')[offset(0)] as field_name, split(p, ':')[offset(1)] as value_previous)])
    )
    full outer join (
      select * from unnest(split(translate(to_json_string(row_current), '{}"', ''))) c,
      unnest([struct(split(c, ':')[offset(0)] as field_name, split(c, ':')[offset(1)] as value_current)]) 
    )
    using(field_name)
    where value_previous != value_current
  ) as diff
from input_data
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi, it seems to be working for the most part of it, but timestamp fields have : character in it, so the split on : is creating some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could add row numbers to your rows using [window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions?hl=es-419), set as the key of the partition your row_id.

Suppose I have an events table, where event_id is the row id, I have several versions of that id on the table, with a window function I will sort version by update_at field and assign a number, number 1 is my latest version

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC
) AS row_number
```

Example of the partition working exactly how you requested:

```sql
WITH events AS (
    SELECT 
        'event_1' AS event_id, 'current_name' AS name, '2021-05-14 23:00:00' AS updated_at
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'event_1' AS event_id, 'previous_name' AS name, '2021-05-14 22:00:00' AS updated_at
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'event_1' AS event_id, 'previous_name_2' AS name, '2021-05-14 21:00:00' AS updated_at
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'event_1' AS event_id, 'previous_name_3' AS name, '2021-05-14 20:00:00' AS updated_at

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        'event_2' AS event_id, 'current_name_2' AS name, '2021-05-14 23:00:00' AS updated_at
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'event_2' AS event_id, 'previous_name_2' AS name, '2021-05-14 22:00:00' AS updated_at
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'event_2' AS event_id, 'previous_name_2_2' AS name, '2021-05-14 21:00:00' AS updated_at
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'event_2' AS event_id, 'previous_name_2_3' AS name, '2021-05-14 20:00:00' AS updated_at

),

add_number_to_rows AS (

    SELECT
        event_id,
        name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC
        ) AS row_number
    FROM events

),

latest_events AS (

    SELECT 
        event_id,
        name,
        (SELECT name FROM add_number_to_rows WHERE row_number = 2 AND events.event_id = add_number_to_rows.event_id) AS previous_name
    FROM add_number_to_rows AS events
    WHERE 
        row_number = 1

)

SELECT 
    event_id,
    name,
    previous_name
FROM latest_events
```

[image: query results]